# split one column to multiple named columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

During a recent restore and issue occurred that may or may not have been present before however now that I'm aware of it I have been tasked with coming up with a solution to it.  We generally write data to multiple column names for each row however I've found that all the fields are going to an Overflow column.  Below is an example of what we have.

Columns we should have Data in:

```
fldDate - fldName    - fldPhoneNumber - fldTransactionID - fldOverflow    
8/15/13 - John Smith - 1012023344     - 123456789        - Null
```

What we are getting:

```
fldDate - fldName    - fldPhoneNumber - fldTransactionID - fldOverflow   
8/15/13 - null       - null           - null             - fldName="John Smith", fldPhoneNumber="1012023344", fldTransactionID="123456789"
```

What i need:

I need to find a way to get the fldOverflow field data back into the correct fields.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous functions out there for separating a delimited field into multiple columns, so that's an option, you could also use `COALESCE()` and string manipulation, something like:

```
SELECT  fldDate 
      , fldName = COALESCE(fldName, SUBSTRING(fldOverflow,CHARINDEX('fldName="',fldOverflow)+9,CHARINDEX(', fldPhone',fldOverflow)-CHARINDEX('fldName="',fldOverflow)-10))
      , fldPhoneNumber 
      , fldTransactionID
      , fldOverflow 
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 0):

I would convert fldOverflow values into xml and then I would use UPDATE thus:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(
    fldName          NVARCHAR(50),
    fldPhoneNumber   VARCHAR(20),
    fldTransactionID INT,
    fldOverflow      NVARCHAR(4000)
);
INSERT INTO @MyTable (fldOverflow)
VALUES (N'fldName="John Smith", fldPhoneNumber="1012023344", fldTransactionID="123456789"');

PRINT 'Before:'
SELECT  *
FROM    @MyTable;

-- I would use, also, transactions thus
-- BEGIN TRANSACTION
UPDATE  x
SET     fldName         =z.fldName,
        fldPhoneNumber  =z.fldPhoneNumber,
        fldTransactionID=z.fldTransactionID,
        fldOverflow     =NULL
-- OUTPUT   deleted.fldName AS OldfldName,inserted.fldName AS NewfldName, ...
FROM    @MyTable x
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT  y.XmlFragment.value('(/row/@fldName)[1]','NVARCHAR(50)') AS fldName,
            y.XmlFragment.value('(/row/@fldPhoneNumber)[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS fldPhoneNumber,
            y.XmlFragment.value('(/row/@fldTransactionID)[1]','INT') AS fldTransactionID
    FROM
    (
        SELECT CONVERT(XML,'<row '+REPLACE(x.fldOverflow,',', ' ')+' />') AS XmlFragment
    ) y
) z
WHERE   x.fldOverflow IS NOT NULL;
-- ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
-- -- COMMIT TRANSACTION

PRINT 'After:'
SELECT  *
FROM    @MyTable;
```

Results:

```
Before:
fldName     fldPhoneNumber  fldTransactionID fldOverflow
----------- --------------- ---------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NULL        NULL            NULL             fldName="John Smith", fldPhoneNumber="1012023344", fldTransactionID="123456789"

After:
fldName     fldPhoneNumber  fldTransactionID fldOverflow
----------- --------------- ---------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
John Smith  1012023344      123456789        NULL
```

**Edit 1:**

```
SELECT  x.fldName AS OldfldName,z.fldName AS NewfldName, ...
FROM    @MyTable x
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT  y.XmlFragment.value('(/row/@fldName)[1]','NVARCHAR(50)') AS fldName,
            y.XmlFragment.value('(/row/@fldPhoneNumber)[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS fldPhoneNumber,
            y.XmlFragment.value('(/row/@fldTransactionID)[1]','INT') AS fldTransactionID
    FROM
    (
        SELECT CONVERT(XML,'<row '+REPLACE(x.fldOverflow,',', ' ')+' />') AS XmlFragment
    ) y
) z
WHERE   x.fldOverflow IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: This is great.  However I'm not a sql master so forgive me if I'm over complicating this.  I have about 3 million rows i need to update how do i get the values of them to work with this query?

Comment: Me neither. If you want to see how are decomposed `fldOverflow` values into `fldName`, `fldPhoneNumber`, etc. then you could use UPDATE with OUTPUT (see UPDATE statement) or SELECT statement instead of UPDATE (see Edit 1).